# Prevent accidentally committing all local changes after adding some changes to the index

Tags: git

I often run `git commit -a`. Sometimes, though, I want to split up the current changes into several commits using `git add`.

Is there a way to trigger a warning when I do `git commit -a` with some changes already added to the index? Otherwise all the work of splitting up the changes is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, first of all: the obvious solution is not using `git commit -a`; I know *you* are aware of that, but there will be people less used to git that come along here by searching and it's worth explicitly noting that `-a` should only be used when wanting to commit all the changes.

You could write a pre-commit hook; look into any git repo's `.git/hooks/` directory to find a couple of example scripts.

The tricky part will be figuring out that you're in a `commit -a` situation; I think the easiest part will just be abusing the powers of `ps` and `grep`:

```
TEST_VARIABLE="$(ps -AF|grep -E '.*git commit.*-a')"
if ["$TEST_VARIABLE" != "" ]; then; ..<WARN HERE>.. ;
```

or similar (note: this is practically pseudo-syntax. Adapt to your favourite shell/scripting language at will).

Comment: This solution simply warns that `commit` has been invoked with `-a`, doesn't it?  The question asks for a warning when this happens _with some changes already added to the index_. The documentation isn't explicit, but I'd be surprised if the hook is invoked before the `-a` has had its effect and the index already contains all local changes.

Comment: @Jeremy: no, what you say about my answer doesn't equal with what I wanted to say; the point is that you're right, the hook is called after `-a` added a lot of files to the staged set (I assume, too!). However, as I understood OP, for his problem it would be sufficient to have some heuristics (e.g. if more than 5 files are updated, `-a` might not be right) and warn then.

Comment: The question seems pretty clearly worded to me.  But in any case, your answer has been accepted, so I guess you're right.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple config flag, but realized that this is not going to happen - ```commit -a``` is in some sense a forced commit that is supposed to overwrite the index.